# Android AGDE in Visual Studio - how to package an AAB?

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm using the Google Visual Studio plugin AGDE to generate an APK - which works fine. I'm trying to get it to output an AAB file - but not having much luck. Does anyone know if AGDE supports generating AAB files?

Comment: I'd like to know that as well.

Comment: The latest version seems to have support for AAB packages - though I haven't managed to get it to work yet.

Answer (score 1):

Got reply here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231836965

Alternatively I invite you to check out my game engine - https://esenthel.com/ it will have Android with AGDE VS support soon.

Comment: The issuetracker doesn't seem to be public